# append some new attributes/fields to validated_data in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on multi user type authentication system currently i am struct in a problem i want to add the user id to the validated_data fields so that user_id can be stored in the vendors table

> serializers.py

```
class CustomerSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model           = Customer
        fields          = "__all__"
    def create(self,validated_data):
        customer       = Customer.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return customer
class  VendorsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model             = Vendors
        fields            = "__all__"
        read_only_fields  = ('added_on','modified_on')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        customer_data={"mobile_number":validated_data.pop('mobile_number'), 
        "password":validated_datapop.('password'),
        "modified_by":validated_data.pop('modified_by'),
        "added_by":validated_data.pop("added_by"),
        "added_source":validated_data.pop("added_source"),
        "customer_role":validated_data.pop("customer_role") }       
        customer = Customer.objects.create_user(**customer_data)

        #Some code here to append comstomer_id to validated_data

        vendor = Vendors.objects.create_user({},**validated_data)
        return vendor
```

> models.py

```
class CustomerManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user( self, mobile_number, password,customer_role,is_active, is_admin, **extra_fields):
        now=timezone.now()
        customer = self.model(mobile_number=mobile_number,    customer_role=customer_role, is_admin=is_admin, is_active=is_active,  last_login=now, added_on=now, modified_on=now,**extra_fields)
        customer.set_password(password)
        customer.save()
        return customer
    def create_user(self, mobile_number,customer_role,password=None,**extra_fields):
        return  self._create_user(mobile_number,password,customer_role,True,False,**extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, mobile_number,customer_role,password=None,**extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(mobile_number,password,'super',True,True,**extra_fields)

class Customer(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    objects = CustomerManager()
    ADDED_SOURCE    = (('website', 'website'),('android', 'android'),('ios', 'ios'),('super', 'super'),('vendor', 'vendor'),)
    id              = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    mobile_number   = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)
    added_source    = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ADDED_SOURCE, default='website')
    added_by        = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='self')
    added_on        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    customer_role   = models.CharField(max_length=8,choices=(('user','user'),('vendor','vendor'),('super','super')),default='user')
    modified_on     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    modified_by     = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='self')
    is_active       = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin        = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['customer_role','modified_by','added_source','added_by',]
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'mobile_number'
    class Meta:
        managed  = True
        db_table = 'tbl_customer'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.mobile_number

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.mobile_number

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mobile_number

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin

class Vendors(models.Model):
    id          = models.AutoField(db_column='Id',primary_key=True)
    user        = models.OneToOneField('Customer')
    username    = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    company     = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    company_register_address  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company_corporate_address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    contact_number            = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    bank_name                 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bank_account_number       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bank_ifsc_code            = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status                    = models.CharField(max_length=8,choices=(('active','active'),('inactive','inactive')))
    class Meta:
        db_table='tbl_vendors'
    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.username)
    def get_full_name(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.company)
    def get_short_name(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.company)
```

How to add the customer id that i will get from Customer object creation to validated_data ?
Any other suggestion about the code is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `user` parameter with value as the created `customer` object when creating `Vendors` object using `.objects.create()` in the `create()` method of `VendorsSerializer`.

You can do something like:

```
class  VendorsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        customer_data={"mobile_number":validated_data.pop('mobile_number'), 
        "password":validated_datapop.('password'),
        "modified_by":validated_data.pop('modified_by'),
        "added_by":validated_data.pop("added_by"),
        "added_source":validated_data.pop("added_source"),
        "customer_role":validated_data.pop("customer_role") } 

        customer = Customer.objects.create_user(**customer_data)

        # pass the created 'customer' object  
        vendor = Vendors.objects.create(user=customer, **validated_data)
        return vendor
```